# Is the longest datapath really the limiting factor on clock cycle speed?

Tags: cpu

I've been watching a lecture series on computer organization and one of the lecturers statements is something along the lines of 'the clock cycle can only be as fast as the time it takes to complete the longest datapath'.

This doesn't make sense to me.  Couldn't chips be architected so that the control unit can check the state of the operation(s) running on it, and block or allow the next use of the path accordingly?

In which case the limiting datapath would be this checking process (which should be pretty fast since its just checking against a few 'dirty bits' given from the rest of the data paths?

Comment: On a 3 GHz processor you have 333 picoseconds to do things. No, you can't architect a chip so that the control unit can check the state of operations running on it and block them in 333 picoseconds.

Comment: Maybe this is too open ended, but why not?  Why couldn't you have single bit memory units representing the completion of datapaths, and then have the control unit operate based on those values?   Is it an issue of the added time for this kind of processing being more than it's worth?